# How to add listener for toast notifications?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, notification, aura-handler, toast

I want to perform an action when a notification happens in my app. The toast event is raised by SFDC which means I do not have access to the calling code.

I have tried adding a handler to the `force:showToast` event with no luck:

```
<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.doAction}"/>
```

There is also this new [notificationsLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_notificationsLibrary.htm?search_text=events) which has the ability to show toasts, but I can't figure out how to tap into it.

Comment: If the component runs inside LEX then firing the `showToast` event will definitely invoke the `doAction` method. Can you please confirm again?

Comment: @Praveen As mentioned I am not firing the event; I am trying to listen for system toast notifications (e.g. when a record is created).

Comment: Could please add more context like where exactly you are trying to listen for the event? if you share context in bit detail then we can help you better.

Comment: This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you want to listen for when a record is saved, force:recordSaveSuccess should do the trick.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's possible! But isn't force:recordSaveSuccess fired only when there's a force:recordEdit? I am not using it in my component. Basically I am trying to capture the outcome of force:createRecord without polling (I have found a way to prevent it from auto-redirecting after success -which is why the framework doesn't define any callback or event for it). I thought the toast notification was a good enough alternative. But as well I have always wanted to know whether I can listen for toast messages. Hence the generic question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get the toast information, as it is an application event, and thus propagates to all interested listeners.

Here's the code I wrote that demonstrates this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    Toast Processor
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.toastInfo}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var toast = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        toast.setParams({
            entityApiName: "Account"
        });
        toast.fire();
    },
    toastInfo: function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("Toast detected: "+event.getParams().message);
    }
})
```

---

Go to the Lightning App Builder, add this component to a new app, activate it, and then pull it up in Lightning.

After creating the new account, you'll get an alert box saying something like "`Toast detected: Client "Test" was created.`" (Note, my Accounts are renamed as Clients).

Comment: What if the toast message is generated by another component? Does your handler still get called? If it matters, I have 3 components: the parent cmp encompasses the child cmp, which dynamically calls up a 3rd cmp which fires the force:createRecord event. I am trying to detect the toast event in the middle cmp (child cmp).